# Why sometimes the whole system crashes?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, google-chrome, ssd

Sometimes when I work with Google Chrome, the whole system suddenly locks and the mouse and keyboard stop working. This usually happens when I'm working with Wampserver. Even once the local database information was lost.

The first time I encountered this problem, my operating system was Windows 7, and now that it is Windows 10, there is still such a problem.

The problem is not solved until I reset the system manually. No program like Task Manager works either.

Could it be a problem with the SSD? I also checked the bad sector and found nothing.

Note, after I upgraded the operating system to Windows 10, it displays this message when booting:

```
WARNING: Please back-up your data and replace your hard disk drive. A failure may be imminent and cause unpredictable fail
```

Comment: Your storage device is failing the lockups are associated with that fact. Act immediately to replace it

Comment: Yes, your drive is failing.  Backup your disk as much as you can immediately.  Do NOT run MySQL  right now as it is disk intensive (or really anything in your WAMP stack).  In fact, disable the service.

Comment: It has been giving this message for more than a year.

Comment: They you are beyond fortunate, bleeding into the realm of blessed, that it is still running.

Comment: @POPI - Have you had the issue of your whole system crashing for that period of time? Unless your willing to replace the drive, we cannot help you, your system is literally telling you the reason it’s crashing.

Answer (score 1):

This is [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) reporting that your hard drive is about to fail.

Backup your data as soon as possible.  After that, go to your hard drives manufacturer's website and download their latest tool for hard drive monitoring.  For example, Samsung used it [Samsung Magician](https://www.samsung.com/us/memory-storage/magician-software/).  Then have it test the drive.  It is *possible* it could just need a firmware update.  However, the software will tell you if the drive is indeed about to fail.